# How to create a max heap in O(N log k) time

Tags: algorithm

I want to create a max heap sort in O(N log k) time with k is the number of k largest elements in the list. However, the pseudocode algorithm below will generate O(N log (N)) time. How can I adjust this in O(N log k) time?

```
function heapsort(array[1..N])
  heapify(array[1..N])
  for i = N to 1 do
    array[i] = extract max(array[1..i])
  end for
end function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is to get the k largest elements using a heap then you can use a min heap instead of max heap.
The size of the heap will be `k`, you then iterate over the list and compare the next element with the top of the heap (min). If it's larger, you extract the min and insert the element.
At the end you'll have a min heap with the k largest elements in it.

```
function KlargestSort(array[1..N])
  min_heap = heapify(array[1..K])

  for i = K+1 to N do
    if (min_heap.top() < A[i])
      min_heap.extract_min()
      min_heap.insert(A[i])
  end for

  for i = 1 to K
    sorted[i] = min_heap.top()
    min_heap.extract_min()
  end for

end function
```

Time complexity `O(NlogK)`
Space complexity `O(K)`

Comment: Thanks for your response. Really appreciate it. Look like I need to make a few adjustment to my Python code.